# Why are my JButton and JLists not appearing? (BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, border-layout

I'm trying to learn swing and work through the task we have been given. I can't see why the code doesn't display the JButtons in the SOUTH section as there is no issue when displaying the textfields, combobox and labels in the CENTER section.

I used the same format to add components to my CENTER section as I did in the SOUTH and EAST but only the center displays anything.

```
public class ProductListGUI{
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem about,importData,inventory,export;

    ProductListGUI(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Assignment 2");

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JList<String> list = new JList<>();
        list.setBounds(600,0,200,600);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

        p1.setLayout(null);
        p1.setBounds(0,0,600,500);
        p1.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
        scrollPane.setLayout(null);
        scrollPane.setBounds(600,0,200,500);
        p3.setLayout(null);
        p3.setBounds(0,500,800,100);
        p3.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));

        JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
        JTextField t1,t2,t3;
        l1=new JLabel("ProductID");
        l1.setBounds(10,100,200,30); 
        t1=new JTextField();  
        t1.setBounds(100,100,200,30);
        l2=new JLabel("Name");
        l2.setBounds(10,150,200,30); 
        t2=new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(100,150,200,30);
        l3=new JLabel("Quantity");
        l3.setBounds(10,250,200,30); 
        t3=new JTextField();
        t3.setBounds(100,250,200,30);
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Product Details"));

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Available for Next Day Delivery");
        checkBox.setBounds(10,300,250,50);

        l4 = new JLabel("Item Type");
        l4.setBounds(10,200,200,30);
        String[] itemType = {"Select type","Homeware","Hobby","Garden"};
        JComboBox dropdown = new JComboBox(itemType);
        dropdown.setBounds(100,200,120,20);

        p1.add(t1);p1.add(l1);p1.add(t2);p1.add(l2);p1.add(t3);p1.add(l3);p1.add(l4);p1.add(dropdown);p1.add(checkBox);


        JButton b1 = new JButton("New Item");
        b1.setBounds(200,550,80,20);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Save");
        b2.setBounds(300,550,80,20);
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Delete Selected");
        b3.setBounds(600,550,80,20);
        b3.setEnabled(false);

        p3.add(b1);p3.add(b2);p3.add(b3);


        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Actions");

        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        importData = new JMenuItem("Import Data");
        inventory = new JMenuItem("Inventory");
        export = new JMenuItem("Export to CSV");

        menu.add(about);menu.add(importData);menu.add(inventory);menu.add(export);
        mb.add(menu);
        
        f.getContentPane().add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.getContentPane().add(p3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);
        f.setSize(800,600);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: What happens without [`setLayout(null)`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswing%5D+null+layout)?

Comment: As a side note, your code is really, really difficult to read.  The creation and usage of objects is terribly far apart from one another and makes it very difficult to figure out what is working with what because everything is so far apart.  If you're up for it, I would urge you to consider using a method per JPanel creation.

Comment: can't believe that was the issue, thank you very much. never would've figured that out as all the tutorials have setLayout(null) in them. Will try to make it more readable too

Comment: all tutorials using null layout are garbage - throw them into the bin they deserve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These code changes should help at least a little bit.

Things that had to change:

- Each JPanel should have a layout.  Setting the layout to `null` (as per TG's comment) is not good.
- The `setBounds()` methods for the buttons were removed.
- The `f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` was moved to the top of the code where `Components` were being added to the JFrame before the layout was set.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ProductListGUI {

    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem about,importData,inventory,export;

    ProductListGUI(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Assignment 2");

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JList<String> list = new JList<>();
        list.setBounds(600,0,200,600);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setBounds(0,0,600,500);
        panel1.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
        scrollPane.setBounds(600,0,200,500);
        panel3.setBounds(0,0,800,100);
        panel3.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));

        JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
        JTextField t1,t2,t3;
        l1=new JLabel("ProductID");
        l1.setBounds(10,100,200,30);
        t1=new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(100,100,200,30);
        l2=new JLabel("Name");
        l2.setBounds(10,150,200,30);
        t2=new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(100,150,200,30);
        l3=new JLabel("Quantity");
        l3.setBounds(10,250,200,30);
        t3=new JTextField();
        t3.setBounds(100,250,200,30);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Product Details"));

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Available for Next Day Delivery");
        checkBox.setBounds(10,300,250,50);

        l4 = new JLabel("Item Type");
        l4.setBounds(10,200,200,30);
        String[] itemType = {"Select type","Homeware","Hobby","Garden"};
        JComboBox dropdown = new JComboBox(itemType);
        dropdown.setBounds(100,200,120,20);

        panel1.add(t1);
        panel1.add(l1);
        panel1.add(t2);
        panel1.add(l2);
        panel1.add(t3);
        panel1.add(l3);
        panel1.add(l4);
        panel1.add(dropdown);
        panel1.add(checkBox);


        JButton b1 = new JButton("New Item");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Save");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Delete Selected");
        b3.setEnabled(false);

        panel3.add(b1);
        panel3.add(b2);
        panel3.add(b3);


        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Actions");

        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        importData = new JMenuItem("Import Data");
        inventory = new JMenuItem("Inventory");
        export = new JMenuItem("Export to CSV");

        menu.add(about);
        menu.add(importData);
        menu.add(inventory);
        menu.add(export);
        mb.add(menu);

        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.getContentPane().add(panel3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);
        f.setSize(800,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProductListGUI gui = new ProductListGUI();
    }
}
```

Here is a very simple BorderLayout example that might help in the future, or not.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createJPanel("CENTER", Color.RED), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createJPanel("NORTH", Color.CYAN), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createJPanel("EAST", Color.LIGHT_GRAY), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createJPanel("SOUTH", Color.GREEN), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createJPanel("WEST", Color.YELLOW), BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createJPanel(String title, Color color) {

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JLabel(title), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jPanel.setBackground(color);

        return jPanel;
    }
}
```